# VB.NET How do I read data as a String from a TextBox?

Tags: vb.net

A few months back I wrote a general server monitoring tool for my own use. Wake on Lan / shutdown / reboot / HW monitor etc...

Since back then I only used it for 1 server, I hardcoded the IPs, MAC Address, and ssh login.

Since then I have 2 more servers to manage, so I thought I would make input fields for the required information to make it more flexible. the problem is with the pinging of the server.

I have a textbox called targetip.

This is how I attempt to ping the server using the input from the textbox:

```
 Dim pingip As String
    pingip = targetip.Text

    If My.Computer.Network.Ping(pingip) Then
        ServerStatus.Text = "Online"
        ServerStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green
```

If instead I just use ("192.168.1.xxx"), it works fine, but with pingip it returns null.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks good to me.

Comment: Is the just one IP address in the textbox, without spaces or any other extra characters? If you use `MsgBox(pingip)` just before doing the ping, does it show what you expect?

Comment: Well as it turns out, if I add the line  targetip.Text = "192.168.1.99" it works fine. But the TextBox has a default value with the same IP, so why does it read null?

Comment: Okay, so in its current state (since so far everything was hardcoded), there is an "Enable Monitoring" checkbox, that triggers pinging, and it was enabled by default. So as soon as I execute the code, it tries to ping the server, but for some reason it can't yet read the textbox value. So I set it to False by default, and then I manually enable monitoring, and it works...

Comment: This is the kind of code you'd want to run in a worker thread.  That often fails as described in vb.net code, the default instance feature for the Form class interacts very poorly with threading.  You get a new instance of the form, you can't see it because its Show() method wasn't called and the targetip.Text is still "".  Add `Sub New` to the class and set a breakpoint on it to diagnose.  Look at Ping.SendAsync() to try to get ahead.

Comment: You could use `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(pingip) AndAlso My.Computer.Network.Ping(pingip) Then`... .

Comment: For this project (since when I fully implement the variable target address feature the pinging/general monitoring will only be enabled after data input competition is confirmed), I won't need any workarounds, but I definitely learned some new things, so thank you to both of you!